# Photodiode connection to ADC

Tags: adc, photodiode

I am designing a product where an ambient light sensor is used to adjust the LCD's brightness.

The following circuit is implemented to read the light sensor. The `LIGHT_SENSE` pin is connected directly to an ADC input of an MCU.

[image: Circuit]

Later on I chose the [SFH-203-P](https://media.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2496046/SFH%20203%20P.pdf) photodiode, which is connected directly to the pins 5 & 6 of the above connector.

Unfortunately, this diode combined with this circuit do not play well. The whole circuit is extremely insensitive to light. A very high luminance is needed to produce any readings at the ADC, much greater than typical room light.

Even worse, the PCBs have been manufactured in large quantities already, so a change in the PCBs is not possible. I am stuck with only changing components.

I tried to change R644. I found out that at 5.6 M ohms, the circuit behaves exactly as needed, and I am about to propose this change.

However I am not confident on using such a high-value resistor for this purpose. I am afraid that such a great impedance may cause problems that I cannot see now, like noise, instability of the circuit etc.

Is it safe to use such a big value for the photodiode biasing?
What problems may arise from such a change?

Comment: I guess a photoresistor CdS would be more suitable for your circuit. The diode needs a transimpedance opamp.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič true, but its difficult to use a photoresistor, due to mechanical constrains :(

Comment: The hero of the day is likely C611 which is acting as a charge reservoir for the ADC conversion process.  I'd check the internal ADC impedance characteristics, don't know if the ADC is a track and hold, sample and hold, etc. but R641 could be modified to improve performance as well.

With such situations, you need to check the possible variations in photodiode response, dark current wrt temperature, etc. with maybe a statistical sample build (random PD selection primarily) to make sure the patch is workable.

Comment: What coinstranints? The diode isn't that different in size.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it would be redundant to suggest that you should have breadboarded this portion of the circuit if you couldn't predict the current from the PD specs. That's a relatively small very fast PIN photodiode.

I would suggest you replace the photodiode with either a much larger one or a phototransistor. There are phototransistors available in a two-lead package.

Using such a high value resistor can cause issues with leakage and other factors (often there is a very significant loading depending on reading rate for typical MCU ADCs) so you would need to study the datasheet for whatever MCU you are using and maybe do some testing.

Comment: Well, I did check the circuit. But due to a mistake while ordering, I am stuck with these PCBs and this diode. I am looking for any decent solution, if possible, before throwing away thousands of diodes...

Answer (score 3):

A very quick examination of the data sheet shows:

> Photocurrent     (EV = 1000 lx, Std. Light A, VR = 5 V) 
>   (typ (min))
>   IP 9.5 (≥ 5) µA

So at 1000 lux (a very bright indoor level), you'll get about 5 to 10 uA of current.

Then the voltage across R644 will (of course) be about 0.05 to 0.1 volt under the equivalent of TV studio lighting. For normal office lighting more like 0.015 to 0.025 volts. Bump the resistor up to 1 M and the voltage will probably be about 1 - 3 volts.

In your case, it takes 5.6 M to get what you want, which suggest that the lighting level is even lower than "normal office lighting". This rather makes sense since you're adjusting an LCD backlight.

I would not expect any real issues with using a larger resistor, except the ones Spehro has already suggested. If your pcb fab and assembly are doing their jobs properly the boards are cleaned of flux after soldering. You ARE using a reputable shop, right? Not necessarily the cheapest you can find? This should take care of leakage. 5.6 M is not all that big a resistor in the normal scheme of things. Noise should not be an issue, especially with R641/C611 in place. You might want to check the data sheet for C611 and look at the expected leakage there.